# How to make an AFTER li background element clicklable?

Tags: html, css

I have an list, with an background arrow after each `<li>`. I need the arrow background to be clicklable as the link is.

```css
.listacategorias  li:after {
  float:right;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background: url("//d26lpennugtm8s.cloudfront.net/stores/567/260/rte/setaazul.png") 
  no-repeat;
  width: 8px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-top:8px;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="listacategorias">
  <li><a href="https://www.playgorila.com/ps3/">Ver tudo de Ps3</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.playgorila.com/ps3/ate-29-90/">Jogos at&eacute;R$29,90</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.playgorila.com/ps3/acessorios/">Acess&oacute;rios econtroles</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.playgorila.com/ps3/consoles/">Consoles</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.playgorila.com/ps3/acao/">Jogos dea&ccedil;&atilde;o</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.playgorila.com/ps3/esporte/">Jogos de esporte</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: is the built in [list-style-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-image) not a good use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might work:

```
.listacategorias li a:after { /*...*/ }
```

you were adding arrow on `<li>` tag and not on `<a>` tag, so the click was going to `<li>`, but yes probably, pseudo elements like `:after` are not clickable..

i hope it helped :)

but if it doesn't, try adding image as `background`, with proper `background-position`